# How to elegantly ignore some return values of a MATLAB function

Tags: matlab, function, return-value

Is it possible to get the 'nth' return value from a function without having to create dummy variables for all `n-1` return values before it?

Let's say, I have the following function in MATLAB:

```
function [a,b,c,d] = func()
a = 1;
b = 2;
c = 3;
d = 4;
```

Now suppose, I'm only interested in the *third* return value. This can be accomplished by creating one dummy variable:

```
[dummy, dummy, variableThatIWillUse, dummy] = func;
clear dummy;
```

But I think this is kind of *ugly*. I would think that you might be able to do something like one of the following things, but you can't:

`[_, _, variableThatIWillUse, _] = func;`

`[, , variableThatIWillUse, ] = func;`

`variableThatIWillUse = func(3);`

`variableThatIWillUse = func()(3);`

Are there any *elegant* ways to do this that do work?

---

So far, the best solution is to simply use the `variableThatIWillUse` as a dummy variable. This saves me from having to create a real dummy variable that pollutes the work-space (or that I would need to clear). In short: the solution is to use the `variableThatIWillUse` for every return value up until the interesting one. Return values after can simply be ignored:

```
[variableThatIWillUse, variableThatIWillUse, variableThatIWillUse] = func;
```

I still think this is very ugly code.

Comment: Aside from using a cell array as I described in my answer, repeating the variable name is probably your only other solution. Hopefully your variable names aren't as long as "variableThatIWillUse". =)

Comment: Actually they are. 'dummy' was just an example. Normally I would use 'variableThatIWillNotUse'. Other variables are named 'variableThatIMightUse', 'variableThatIWillUse2' and 'variableThatCanBarelyFitOnA80CharacterLine'. I'm researching the correlation between long names and homicide ratings. ;)

Comment: Actually since R2009b ignoring function returns is solved more elegantly using the '~'-Char.
e.g.: [~,b] = sort(rand(10,1))

Comment: FOR NEW READERS: ^ should be the correct answer. See [ManWithSleeve's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1404597/44330) below

Comment: In you example if you only want the 3rd output argument you shall use:[ variableThatIWillUse,variableThatIWillUse,variableThatIWillUse] = func; No need to clear a dummy variable. For newer MATLAB versions >=R2009b, use [~,~,variableThatIWillUse] = func;

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This is somewhat of a hack, but it works:

First a quick example function:

```
Func3 = @() deal(1,2,3);
[a,b,c]=Func3();
% yields a=1, b=2, c=3
```

Now the key here is that if you use a variable **twice** on the left-hand side of a multiple-expression assignment, an earlier assignment is clobbered by the later assignment:

```
[b,b,c]=Func3();
% yields b=2, c=3

[c,c,c]=Func3();
% yields c=3
```

(Just to check, I also verified that this technique works with `[mu,mu,mu]=polyfit(x,y,n)` if all you care about from `polyfit` is the third argument.)

---

There's a better approach; see [ManWithSleeve's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1404597/44330) instead.

Comment: Had not thought about solving it like this. However, I feel this solution sacrifices the clarity of intent for cleverness.

Comment: I personally just use [junk, junk, c] = function_call() and assume both that "junk" is never an important variable and if it contains a lot of memory that I will clear it if necessary.

Comment: to the downvoter: Why the -1? This answer was written before R2009b was even released, so @ManWithSleeve's answer wouldn't have worked at the time. Now, of course, that's the right approach.

Comment: Maybe a comment in the first line of your answer would be helpful? I just came here through google, so it seems it's worth updating.

Comment: The left-to-right assignment is not officially guaranteed by The MathWorks, so you probably shouldn't rely on using c after [c,c,c] = myFunc(). (See Comment #26 here: http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2009/09/11/matlab-release-2009b-best-new-feature-or/)

Comment: You should simply use the tilde `~` operator, per documentation: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/ignore-function-outputs.html

Answer (score 239):

With MATLAB Version 7.9 (R2009b) you can use a ~, e.g.,

```
[~, ~, variableThatIWillUse] = myFunction();
```

Note that the `,` isn't optional. Just typing `[~ ~ var]` will not work, and will throw an error.

See the [release notes](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/rn/br5fo8o-1.html#br65zmd-1) for details.

Comment: Kind of annoying that it isn't "_". (I suppose that was taken already?)

Comment: @SamB: although using the `not` operator as in `don't care` isn't that bad either

Comment: Do note that the `,` isn't optional. Just typing `[~ ~ var]` will *not* work, and will throw an error.

Comment: I would say that this is the "correct" answer. The other are just hacks to fix a problem that does not exist. No pun intended though...

Comment: The question was posed in 2009 prior to R2009b, at which time the ~ did not work.

Answer (score 37):

If you wish to use a style where a variable will be left to fall into the bit bucket, then a reasonable alternative is

```
[ans, ans, variableThatIWillUse] = myfun(inputs);
```

`ans` is of course the default junk variable for MATLAB, getting overwritten often in the course of a session.

While I do like the new trick that MATLAB now allows, using a `~` to designate an ignored return variable, this is a problem for backwards compatibility, in that users of older releases will be unable to use your code.

I generally avoid using new things like that until at least a few MATLAB releases have been issued to ensure there will be very few users left in the lurch. For example, even now I find people are still using an old enough MATLAB release that they cannot use anonymous functions.

Comment: Yes, it's clever, but the native Matlab editor will give a warning if you assign anything to the ans variable. I don't think having warnings are very elegant...

Comment: You can turn the warning off.

End the line with this comment string   %#ok

Mlint will then ignore this. No warnings.

Answer (score 14):

Here's another option you can use. First make a cell array to capture all the outputs (you can use the [NARGOUT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/nargout.html) function to determine how many outputs a given function returns):

```
a = cell(1,3);  % For capturing 3 outputs
% OR...
a = cell(1,nargout(@func));  % For capturing all outputs from "func"
```

Then call the function as follows:

```
[a{:}] = func();
```

Then simply remove the element from **a** that you want, and overwrite **a**:

```
a = a{3};  % Get the third output
```

Answer (score 9):

I wrote a kth out function:

```matlab
function kth = kthout(k, ffnc, varargin)
% kthout: take the kth varargout from a func call %FOLDUP
%
% kth = kthout(k, ffnc, varargin)
%
% input:
%  k                      which varargout to get
%  ffnc                   function to call;
%  varargin               passed to ffnc;
% output:
%  kth                    the kth argout;

[outargs{1:k}] = feval(ffnc, varargin{:});
kth = outargs{k};

end %function
```

You can then call

```
val_i_want = kthout(3, @myfunc, func_input_1, func_input_2);
```

You could also wrap up the function like:

```
func_i_want = @(varargin)(kthout(3, @myfunc,varargin{:}));  % Assuming you want the third output.
```

After which you use

```
val_i_want = func_i_want(func_input_1, func_input_2);
```

Note that there is overhead associated with using anonymous functions like this, and this is not something I would do in code that would be called thousands of times.

Answer (score 4):

In MATLAB 2010a, I found a neat way of doing what you are asking for.

It is simply to use the character "~" (without the quotes of course) as your dummy variable (as many as you want when returning multiple parameters). This also works for input parameters to functions if the functions are designed to handle missing data.

I don't know if this existed in previous versions, but I just came across it recently.

Comment: Didn't you see the previous answer?

Comment: Covered in two previous answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a function (or anonymous function) that only returns selected outputs, e.g.

```
select = @(a,b) a(b);
```

Then you can call your function like this:

```
select(func,2);
select(func,1:3);
```

Or you can assign the output to a variable:

```
output(1,2:4) = select(func,1:3);
```

Comment: doesnt work for me. Tried `decimatedfftx = select(fft(x,12),1:4:12);`

Comment: `select(func,2)` calls `func(2)`. I don't see where this selects output arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason not to use ans(n). Like this:

```
size(rand([5 10 20 40]));

b = ans(2);
```

It gives b = 10, and this way would be compatible with all MATLAB versions. Note that size() here is just used to represent any function that has multiple return variables.

Furthermore, this works to get the second output argument when you don't know how many arguments there will be! Whereas, if you do this:

```
[~, b] = size(a);
```

Then b = 8000! (You need to end with `~`, to catch more arguments!)

Comment: This answer assumes the variable being returned is a vector, which was probably not what the OP meant.

Comment: This makes no sense. `size(a)` and `[b,c]=size(a)` return different things. Functions in MATLAB change behaviour based on the number of output arguments.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding this answer. I don't know how this contributes to the quality of the answers here, let alone that this doesn't directly answer the original question.

Comment: It's 6 years later, and I no longer use Matlab. As far as I remember, the function "size()" was irrelevant – I just used it as a function that would return multiple arguments. The point is that I can simply call func() and then ans(n) to get the value of returned variable number n. This appeared to work well for certain situations and be backwards compatible. It may only work with certain functions of course, or variable types, whatever. That's as much as I can help 6 years later.