# How do I get the second return value from a function without using temporary variables?

Tags: matlab

I have a function that returns two values, like so:

```
[a b] = myfunc(x)
```

Is there a way to get the second return value without using a temporary variable, and without altering the function?

What I'm looking for is something like this:

```
abs(secondreturnvalue(myfunc(x)))
```

Comment: What about using a class instead of a function with corresponding 'getter' methods. You might get something like abs(myfunc.secondReturnValue(x)).

Comment: Upvoting this as a pseudo-feature request to MathWorks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Unless there is some pressing need to do this, I would probably advise against it. The clarity of your code will suffer. Storing the outputs in temporary variables and then passing these variables to another function will make your code cleaner, and the different ways you could do this are outlined here: [How to elegantly ignore some return values of a MATLAB function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747296/how-to-elegantly-ignore-some-return-values-of-a-matlab-function).

However, if you *really* want or need to do this, the only feasible way I can think of would be to create your own function `secondreturnvalue`. Here's a more general example called `nth_output`:

```
function value = nth_output(N,fcn,varargin)
  [value{1:N}] = fcn(varargin{:});
  value = value{N};
end
```

And you would call it by passing as inputs 1) the output argument number you want, 2) a [function handle](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/function_handle.html) to `myfunc`, and 3) whatever input arguments you need to pass to `myfunc`:

```
abs(nth_output(2,@myfunc,x))
```

Answer (score 28):

not that i know of. `subsref` doesn't seem to work in this case, possibly because the second variable isn't even returned from the function.

since matlab 2009b it is possible to use the notation

```
[~, b] = function(x)
```

if you don't need the first argument, but this still uses a temporary variable for `b`.