# How to save the use of a temporary variable in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [matlab array index without assigning to a local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627107/matlab-array-index-without-assigning-to-a-local-variable)

Hi All,

I am having a very basic question in using matlab. I want to save the use of `a` in the following code when using matlab:

```
a=[1,2,3]
a(2:3)
```

[1,2,3](2:3) is now allowed.

??? [1 2 3](2:3)

|

Error: Unbalanced or misused parentheses or brackets.

Is there any function to get the element of a vector besides the [] operator? The reason I ask this is that: sometimes when a function returns a vector and I want to get only the second element in the vector, I do not want to save the function return to a temporary variable before I get its second element. Is there any way?

Many thanks!

Comment: Questions along this same line have been asked before: [matlab array index without assigning to a local variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627107), [How to elegantly ignore some return values of a MATLAB function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747296), [How do I get the second return value from a function without using temporary variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710466)

Comment: @gnovice: And here I was about to say it wasn't possible :)

Comment: by "now allowed" do you mean "not allowed"?

Answer (score 1):

This might be of interest:

[File Central - Direct Indexing of Function Calls](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26570-direct-indexing-of-function-calls-oop-exercise)