# Access second output of Matlab procedure directly

Tags: matlab

I'm not very good at programming and new to matlab, so sorry if I'm not using the right terminology.

If I use the e.g. fminbnd procedure in Matlab first i get the x-value which minimises and then i get the function value. Is there a neat way for me to get just the minimum function value.
To make it clear, for me it seems I have to do:

```
[x,y] = fminbnd(h,-10,10)
```

when I only need y. Is there any way for me to not get x?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710466/how-do-i-get-the-second-return-value-from-a-function-without-using-temporary-var

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `~` to suppress `x` output. Only available in later versions of matlab (=> r2009b).

```
[~, y] = fminbnd(h, -10, 10);
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! What now if I want -y? Do you know if i can get that directly (I'm maximising by minimising minus the function.).

Comment: @Henrik I don't think you can assign to `-y` in general. However, you can of course simply use `-y` in later formulas, or do `y = -y` right after finding it.