# Matlab: directly access a specific return value of functions

Tags: matlab, function, variables

I would like to use a specific return value from a function and pass it to another function, as a one-liner.

The problem is that I can't simply access the return value like someFunction(x, y, z){2} or [2] or (2),
for example:

```
regexpi(str,'[a-z]+','match') % returns a cell array, i just need the first match.(btw, ^ doesn't work in matlab?)
```

if I would like to take the first child of the `regexpi()` and pass it to `myfun()`, what I want is:

```
myfun(regexpi(str,'[a-z]+','match')(1))
```

but I got an error instead:

```
Error: ()-indexing must appear last in an index expression.
```

Is there any workaround? thanks!

Comment: I suggest you just do it in two lines. Your code will be more readable that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it cant be done in matlab, it is just not supported. The only way I know of, that is somehow elegant, is to create itemgetter (something ala [itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) in python). For example,

```
itemgetter = @(r, idx) r{idx}


#now get first returned argument
itemgetter(regexpi(str,'[a-z]+','match'), 1)
```

For more info, and other possible ways have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710466/how-do-i-get-the-second-return-value-from-a-function-without-using-temporary-var).