# Index of Max Value from by grouping using varfun

Tags: matlab, sorting, matlab-table

I have a table with Ids and Dates. I would like to retrieve the index of the max date for each Id.

My initial approach is so:
varfun(@max, table, 'Grouping Variables', 'Id', 'InputVariables','Date');

This obviously gives me the date rather than the index. 
I noted that the max function will return both the maxvalue and maxindex when specified:
[max_val, max_idx] = max(values);

How can I define an anonymous function using max to retrieve max_idx? I would then use it in the var_fun to get my result.

I'd prefer not to declare a cover function (as opposed to a anon func)over max() as: 
1.  I'm working in a script and would rather not create another function file
2. I'm unwilling to change my current script to a function

Thanks a million guys,

Comment: Can we assume each date is just one `double` value?

Comment: date is in fact just one double value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `varfun` is the right approach here, as

> `varfun(func,A)` applies the function `func` separately to each variable of
>       the table `A`.

This would only make sense if you wanted to apply it to multiple columns.

### Simple approach:

Simply go with the loop approach: First find the different IDs using `unique`, then for each ID find the indices of the maximum dates. (This assumes your dates are in a numerical format which can be compared directly using `max`.)
I did rename your variable `table` to `t`, as otherwise we would be overwriting the built-in function `table`.

```
uniqueIds = unique(t.Id);
for i = 1:numel(uniqueIds)
    equalsCurrentId = t.Id==uniqueIds(i); 
    globalIdxs = find(equalsCurrentId);
    [~, localIdxsOfMax] = max(t.Date(equalsCurrentId));
    maxIdxs{i} = globalIdxs(localIdxsOfMax);
end
```

As you mentioned your `Ids` are actually strings instead of numbers, you will have to change the line: `equalsCurrentId = t.Id==uniqueIds(i);` to

```
 equalsCurrentId = strcmp(t.Id, uniqueIds{i});
```

### Approach using `accumarray`:

If you prefer a more compact style, you could use this solution inspired by [*Luis Mendo*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28420410/3139711), which should work for both numerical and string Ids:

```
[uniqueIds, ~, global2Unique] = unique(t.Id);
maxDateIdxsOfIdxSubset = @(I) {I(nth_output(2, @max, t.Date(I)))};
maxIdxs = accumarray(global2Unique, 1:length(t.Id), [], maxDateIdxsOfIdxSubset);
```

This uses `nth_output` of *gnovice*'s [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3711304/3139711).

### Usage:

Both above solutions will yield: A vector `uniqueIds` with a corresponding `cell`-array `maxIdxs`, in a way that `maxIdxs{i}` are the indices of the maximum dates of `uniqueIds(i)`.
If you only want a single index, even though there are multiple entries where the maximum is attained, use the following to strip away the unwanted data:

```
maxIdxs = cellfun(@(X) X(1), maxIdxs);
```

Comment: Perhaps use a different name for the `table`-type variable?

Comment: @LuisMendo: I was unsure how to handle this, as the OP was using this convention. I guess I should rename it and point out the shadowing.

Comment: @LuisMendo: I let your approach inspire me to give `accumarray` another chance. :-)

Comment: Did you mention readability? :-P You have my upvote already BTW!

Comment: @knedlsepp thanks for breaking this down for me, very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming your **Ids are positive integers** and and your **Dates are numbers**.

If you wanted the maximum Date for each Id, it would be a perfect case for [`accumarray`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) with the `max` function. In the following I'll use `f` to denote a generic function passed to `accumarray`.

The fact that you want the *index* of the maximum makes it a little trickier (and more interesting!). The problem is that the Dates corresponding to a given Id are passed to `f` without any reference to their original index. Therefore, an `f` based on `max` can't help. But you can make the indices "pass through" `accumarray` as *imaginary parts* of the Dates.

So: if you want just *one* maximizing index (even if there are several) for each Id:

```
result = accumarray(t.Id,...  %// col vector of Id's
    t.Date+1j*(1:size(t,1)).', ... %'// col vector of Dates (real) and indices (imag)
    [], ... %// default size for output
    @(x) imag(x(find(real(x)==max(real(x))),1))); %// function f
```

Note that the function `f` here maximizes the *real* part and then extracts the *imaginary* part, which contains the original index.

Or, if you want *all* maximizing indices for each Id:

```
result = accumarray(t.Id,...  %// col vector of Id's
    t.Date+1j*(1:size(t,1)).', ... %'// col vector of Dates (real) and indices (imag)
    [], ... %// default size for output
    @(x) {imag(x(find(real(x)==max(real(x)))))}); %// function f
```

If your **Ids are strings**: transform them into numeric labels using the third output of [`unique`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html), and then proceed as above:

```
[~, ~, NumId] = unique(t.Id);
```

and then either

```
result = accumarray(NumId,...  %// col vector of Id's
    t.Date+1j*(1:size(t,1)).', ... %'// col vector of Dates (real) and indices (imag)
    [], ... %// default size for output
    @(x) imag(x(find(real(x)==max(real(x))),1))); % function f
```

or

```
result = accumarray(NumId,...  %// col vector of Id's
    t.Date+1j*(1:size(t,1)).', ... %'// col vector of Dates (real) and indices (imag)
    [], ... %// default size for output
    @(x) {imag(x(find(real(x)==max(real(x)))))}); %// function f
```

Comment: I dropped my initial thought of `accumarray` having no idea how to map the local indices to global ones. Even though it doesn't make for an easy reading, using complex numbers it is a great hack to say least. ;-) [Also thank god our universe's time is real. This makes our watchmakers work a lot easier. :-P]

Comment: @knedlsepp It always gives me satisfaction to use complex numbers for this kind of tricks :-) Their use here is not really close to the true nature of complex numbers, though. ...Which makes it a little more hackish, hahaha.

Comment: @LuisMendo My Ids are actually strings. Perhaps I can map them over to integers.

Comment: @user2353644 That can be done easily with the third output of `unique`. Probably `[~, ~, numId] = unique(t.Id);` would suffice, but I can't test right now. I'll come back later

Comment: @LuisMendo you sir have added two more tools to my toolbox (accumarray and img num tricks), thanks

Comment: @user2353644 Glad I could help! I have added the code for numeric Ids. See updated answer