# Divide an image into non-overlapping blocks and applying the 2D DWT on each block

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, dwt

I am working on creating an image splicing detection software so I need to divide the image into non-overlapping blocsk and apply Discrete Meyer Wavelet Transform on each block of the image

I have tried the `blockproc` function to do that but I got no result:

```
I = imread('pears.png');

fun = @(block_struct)...
    dwt2(block_struct.data,'dmey');

C = blockproc(I,[64 64],fun);
```

So how can I access the `[cA,cH,cV,cD`] of `dwt2` using the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`blockproc`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/blockproc.html) assumes that you are outputting an actual image.  You cannot use this for multiple outputs.  If you truly want this to work with `blockproc`, you will unfortunately need to call `blockproc` four times, with each time extracting the different set of coefficients for the directions.  Also note that the 2D DWT only works for **grayscale** images, so you need to convert to grayscale before actually doing any processing.  The pears image you've chosen is a colour / RGB image.

I'd like to reference this post on how to select the `N`th output given an input function:  [How do I get the second return value from a function without using temporary variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710466/how-do-i-get-the-second-return-value-from-a-function-without-using-temporary-var).  You will need to save this code to a file called `nth_output.m`, which allows you to programatically extract all output variables from a function and choose only one output.

```
function value = nth_output(N,fcn,varargin)
  [value{1:N}] = fcn(varargin{:});
  value = value{N};
end
```

Simply omitting the extra output arguments when you call the function only gives you the first output, which is what your `blockproc` code is doing.  Once you do that, it's a matter of creating 4 anonymous functions to capture each output from `dwt2`, and running `blockproc` 4 times.  Make sure you specify which output you want for each of the anonymous functions, so `1` up to `4` and you simply provide a handle to the function you want to run in addition to the input arguments that go into the function.

Therefore, try something like this:

```
I = rgb2gray(imread('pears.png'));
fun1 = @(block_struct) nth_output(1, @dwt2, block_struct.data,'dmey');
fun2 = @(block_struct) nth_output(2, @dwt2, block_struct.data,'dmey');
fun3 = @(block_struct) nth_output(3, @dwt2, block_struct.data,'dmey');
fun4 = @(block_struct) nth_output(4, @dwt2, block_struct.data,'dmey');
I = rgb2gray(I);
cA = blockproc(I,[64 64],fun1);
cH = blockproc(I,[64 64],fun2);
cV = blockproc(I,[64 64],fun3);
cD = blockproc(I,[64 64],fun4);
```

`cA`, `cH`, `cV`, and `cD` contain the DWT coefficients you need for each set of directions.

Comment: So I need to apply 2-level dwt I write the code as 
cA2 = blockproc(cA,[64 64],fun1);
cH2 = blockproc(cH,[64 64],fun2);
cV2 = blockproc(cV,[64 64],fun3);
cD2 = blockproc(cD,[64 64],fun4);

If  this is true, can I round all 8 subband of the two level to the nearest integer number and take its absolute value

Comment: @MohammedKassem Yes you would have to repeat that process for the 2-level decomposition.  I'm unsure what you mean by your last comment with the absolute value.

Comment: @MohammedKassem Did I answer your question?