# MATLAB black hole variable

Tags: matlab, syntax

Does MATLAB have a "blackhole" or discard variable?

Say I'm doing something like:

```
[ rows cols ] = size( A ) ;
```

But I don't want rows to be stored.  Is there a "black hole" variable where I can send values to die?

So the assignment would be like

```
[ BLACKHOLE, cols ] = size( A ) ;
```

Where BLACKHOLE means throw the value away and don't create a variable for it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to elegantly ignore some return values of a MATLAB function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747296/how-to-elegantly-ignore-some-return-values-of-a-matlab-function)

Comment: @gnovice: the search fu is strong with you. I'll leave my answer up for the second part for the moment.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For 2009b or later, there is the tilde sign "~"

```
[~,cols] = size(A);
```

Alternatively, in your specific case

```
cols = size(A,2);
```

Answer (score 1):

For compatibility with Matlab versions prior to 2009b you can use the following technique

[cols, cols] = size(A);

See http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2010/01/11/about-the-unused-argument-syntax-in-r2009b/ for example