# Ignoring an output from a Matlab function

Tags: function, matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to elegantly ignore some return values of a MATLAB function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747296/how-to-elegantly-ignore-some-return-values-of-a-matlab-function)

I have a Matlab function with two outputs. Sometimes I use both outputs.

```
function [output1 output2] = myFunction(input)
[a b] = myFunction(input);
```

Other times I only need output1 and don't want to waste memory assigning output2

```
a = myFunction(input);
```

However, I can't figure out a simple way to give the reverse scenario (only need output2 and don't want to waste memory assigning output1). I thought it would be something like

```
[~ b] = myFunction(input)
```

but that doesn't seem to work. Anybody have suggestions for a quick solution? Thanks for your help!

Comment: you are missing a comma: `[~,b] = myFunction(input)`

Answer (score 2):

It's `[~, b]`, not `[~ b]`. The comma is missing.

Comment: I get the following error when I add the comma: Error: Expression or statement is incorrect--possibly
unbalanced (, {, or [.

Comment: What does your call look like? Post the actual line you use to call it.

Comment: @yy08: `~` was only introduced in MATLAB R2009b, what version are you working with?

Comment: '[~, b] = myFunction(input)'. I'm using version 2007b so that might explain it.

Comment: Tried it on a computer with 2010b. Works fine. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

the object will be created inside myFunction either way, unless your input has a way to prevent the creation.  If you can prevent the creation internally, you can modify myFunction to return a cell array or other structure, from which you can decide which elements to keep.   If your concern is that [dontwant b] is wasting matlab memory by holding dontwant, then you might want to delete dontwant from your workspace by calling

```
clear dontwant;
```