# Unbalanced parenthesis or bracket

Tags: matlab

I assign the command as follow:

```
[r,~]=size(alternative)
```

The problem I get:
**Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket.**

Anyone knows why? I have alternative size of 252x6

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are running an old Matlab version (older than R2009b).
The use of `~` as unassigned to argument is relatively new feature to Matlab.

Use instead:

```
[r, ignore] = size( alternative );
```

See [How to elegantly ignore some return values of a MATLAB function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747296/how-to-elegantly-ignore-some-return-values-of-a-matlab-function) on other methods to accomplish what you are trying.

PS,
Specifically for `size` you can specify the dimension you are interested in as an input argument:

```
r = size( alternative, 1 ); % get only the number of rows
```

Comment: Great. Works! thanks, as u siad, i used R2009a. :) Thanks again