# Mathematic graphs with matlab gui

Tags: matlab, user-interface, graph

I need to create a GUI in Matlab that enables me to draw graphs interactively, and the give values to the edges and vertices.

I then need to return these values (x, y, value) for edges and (x1, y1, x2, y2, value) for vertices.

Unfortunately I don't even know where to start. I created a gui that lets me draw lines interactively, with 2 different methods, but I don't know how to continue. Please help.

Comment: Can you post what you have tried and failed to accomplish?  We aren't here to solve your homework for you, but to nudge you in the right direction.  Demonstrating effort on your own is crucial.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/peo1zk3iyra1jbj/MATLAB.rar

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can always handle mouse events to enable interactive drawing. I spent some time on this and came up with the following GUI.

```
function interactive_graph_gui
    % data
    showLabels = false;   % flag to determine whether to show node labels
    prevIdx = [];         % keeps track of 1st node clicked in creating edges
    selectIdx = [];       % used to highlight node selected in listbox
    pts = zeros(0,2);     % x/y coordinates of vertices
    adj = sparse([]);     % sparse adjacency matrix (undirected)

    % create GUI
    h = initGUI();

    function h = initGUI()
        h.fig = figure('Name','Interactive Graph', 'Resize','off');
        h.ax = axes('Parent',h.fig, 'ButtonDownFcn',@onMouseDown, ...
            'XLim',[0 1], 'YLim',[0 1], 'XTick',[], 'YTick',[], 'Box','on', ...
            'Units','pixels', 'Position',[160 20 380 380]);

        h.list = uicontrol('Style','listbox', 'Parent',h.fig, 'String',{}, ...
            'Min',1, 'Max',1, 'Value',1, ...
            'Position',[20 80 130 320], 'Callback',@onSelect);
        uicontrol('Style','pushbutton', 'Parent',h.fig, 'String','Clear', ...
            'Position',[20 20 60 20], 'Callback',@onClear);
        uicontrol('Style','pushbutton', 'Parent',h.fig, 'String','Export', ...
            'Position',[90 20 60 20], 'Callback',@onExport);
        uicontrol('Style','pushbutton', 'Parent',h.fig, 'String','Delete', ...
            'Position',[50 50 60 20], 'Callback',@onDelete);

        h.cmenu = uicontextmenu('Parent',h.fig);
        h.menu = uimenu(h.cmenu, 'Label','Show labels', 'Checked','off', ...
            'Callback',@onCMenu);
        set(h.list, 'UIContextMenu',h.cmenu)

        h.pts = line(NaN, NaN, 'Parent',h.ax, 'HitTest','off', ...
            'Marker','o', 'MarkerSize',10, 'MarkerFaceColor','b', ...
            'LineStyle','none');
        h.selected = line(NaN, NaN, 'Parent',h.ax, 'HitTest','off', ...
            'Marker','o', 'MarkerSize',10, 'MarkerFaceColor','y', ...
            'LineStyle','none');
        h.prev = line(NaN, NaN, 'Parent',h.ax, 'HitTest','off', ...
            'Marker','o', 'MarkerSize',20, 'Color','r', ...
            'LineStyle','none', 'LineWidth',2);
        h.edges = line(NaN, NaN, 'Parent',h.ax, 'HitTest','off', ...
            'LineWidth',2, 'Color','g');
        h.txt = [];

    end

    function onMouseDown(~,~)
        % get location of mouse click (in data coordinates)
        p = get(h.ax, 'CurrentPoint');

        % determine whether normal left click was used or otherwise
        if strcmpi(get(h.fig,'SelectionType'), 'Normal')
            % add a new node
            pts(end+1,:) = p(1,1:2);
            adj(end+1,end+1) = 0;
        else
            % add a new edge (requires at least 2 nodes)
            if size(pts,1) < 2, return; end

            % hit test (find node closest to click location: euclidean distnce)
            [dst,idx] = min(sum(bsxfun(@minus, pts, p(1,1:2)).^2,2));
            if sqrt(dst) > 0.025, return; end

            if isempty(prevIdx)
                % starting node (requires a second click to finish)
                prevIdx = idx;
            else
                % add the new edge
                adj(prevIdx,idx) = 1;
                prevIdx = [];
            end
        end

        % update GUI
        selectIdx = [];
        redraw()
    end

    function onDelete(~,~)
        % check that list of nodes is not empty
        if isempty(pts), return; end

        % delete selected node
        idx = get(h.list, 'Value');        
        pts(idx,:) = [];
        adj(:,idx) = [];
        adj(idx,:) = [];

        % clear previous selections
        if prevIdx == idx
            prevIdx = [];
        end
        selectIdx = [];

        % update GUI
        set(h.list, 'Value',max(min(idx,size(pts,1)),1))
        redraw()
    end

    function onClear(~,~)
        % reset everything
        prevIdx = [];
        selectIdx = [];
        pts = zeros(0,2);
        adj = sparse([]);

        % update GUI
        set(h.list, 'Value',1)
        redraw()
    end

    function onExport(~,~)
        % export nodes and adjacency matrix to base workspace
        assignin('base', 'adj',(adj+adj')>0)  % make it symmetric
        assignin('base', 'xy',pts)
    end

    function onSelect(~,~)
        % update index of currently selected node
        selectIdx = get(h.list, 'Value');
        redraw()
    end

    function onCMenu(~,~)
        % flip state
        showLabels = ~showLabels;
        redraw()
    end

    function redraw()
        % edges
        p = nan(3*nnz(adj),2);
        [i,j] = find(adj);
        p(1:3:end,:) = pts(i,:);
        p(2:3:end,:) = pts(j,:);
        set(h.edges, 'XData',p(:,1), 'YData',p(:,2))

        % nodes
        set(h.pts, 'XData',pts(:,1), 'YData',pts(:,2))
        set(h.prev, 'XData',pts(prevIdx,1), 'YData',pts(prevIdx,2))
        set(h.selected, 'XData',pts(selectIdx,1), 'YData',pts(selectIdx,2))

        % list of nodes
        set(h.list, 'String',num2str(pts,'(%.3f,%.3f)'))

        % node labels
        if ishghandle(h.txt), delete(h.txt); end
        if showLabels
            set(h.menu, 'Checked','on')
            h.txt = text(pts(:,1)+0.01, pts(:,2)+0.01, ...
                num2str((1:size(pts,1))'), ...
                'HitTest','off', 'FontSize',8, ...
                'VerticalAlign','bottom', 'HorizontalAlign','left');
        else
            set(h.menu, 'Checked','off')
        end

        % force refresh
        drawnow
    end

end
```

[image: gui]

It all boils down to handling the [`ButtonDownFcn` callback](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes_props.html#zmw57dd0e31686) of the axis object, and querying the location of the last mouse click using the [`CurrentPoint` property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes_props.html#zmw57dd0e32705).

Here is a list of the possible ways to interact with the GUI:

- left-click inside the axis to create vertices
- right-click on two nodes to create an edge
- use the listbox to select and highlight nodes. Use the "delete" button to remove the selected vertex.
- The "clear" button resets everything
- The "export" button create two variables in the base workspace containing the vertices 2D coordinates (N-by-2 matrix) and the edges (as a sparse N-by-N matrix). You can use those variables with other graph functions as usual:

  ```
  gplot(adj, xy, 'b.-')
  ```
- Finally you can right click on the listbox. This will bring up a popup menu, containing the option to display labels for the vertices.

You can extend the above code to assign values to vertices. For example you could use the callback function of the listbox to assign values to vertices (display an input dialog when the user selects an item from the list). You could also use the same technique shown of handling the `ButtonDownFcn` callback. Similarly you could create a second listbox to display the edges and handle the assignment of values in the same manner... I will that part to you :)

Comment: It looks great on these pics thank you. I just have an error after I placed the elements to the gui, just like you did, and pasting the code to the m file of the gui. It gives me error on this line function onMouseDown(~,~) on the ~ signs.

Comment: @geryjuhasz: you probably have an older MATLAB version. `~` is used to ignore variables, so in your case just replace it with a dummy variable: http://stackoverflow.com/q/747296/97160

Comment: got it. I am upgrading now and have a check in the new version. Thank you!

Comment: @geryjuhasz: While I do advice you to upgrade to newer versions if you have access, this is minor issue easily solved, and it shouldnt stop you for trying the code in your current version :)

Comment: That`s working perfectly, thanks. I`m now trying to extend to assign values to edges and vertices. Thank`s a lot!

Comment: I`m now trying to add a function to listbox click event. Here is my code:
set(h.list, 'ButtonDownFcn', {@myCallbackFcn});
function myCallbackFcn(eventData)
   % Determine the click type
   % (can similarly test for CTRL/ALT/SHIFT-click)
   
   if eventData.isMetaDown  % right-click is like a Meta-button
      clickType = 'Right-click';
   else
      clickType = 'Left-click';
   end
 
   fprintf('%s on item\n', clickType);
end

And it gives me error only on right-click event on a listbox item, on left click nothing happens.

Comment: The error is:
Error using guistack2013>myCallbackFcn
Too many input arguments.
 
Error while evaluating uicontrol ButtonDownFcn

Comment: @geryjuhasz: its easier to just use the `'Callback'` of the listbox (ie the existing `onSelect` function). As for you specific error message, its because all callback functions receive two input arguments. This is explained in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the mouse to draw interactively you can use the function `ginput`. [Here](http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/matlab/ref/ginput.html) there is the manual.
I found very useful also [this example](http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/matlab/creating_plots/interactive-plotting.html).

Comment: Thank for the anwser. I am currently using this:
axis([0 10 0 10])
hold on
% Initially, the list of points is empty.
xy = [];
n = 0;
% Loop, picking up the points.
disp('Left mouse button picks points.')
disp('Right mouse button picks last point.')
but = 1;
while but == 1
    [xi,yi,but] = ginput(1);
    plot(xi,yi,'ro')
    n = n+1;
    xy(:,n) = [xi;yi];
end
% Interpolate with a spline curve and finer spacing.
t = 1:n;
ts = 1: 0.1: n;
%xys = spline(t,xy,ts);

    line(xy(1,:), xy(2,:))

% Plot the interpolated curve.
%plot(xys(1,:),xys(2,:),'b-');
hold off