# Get only the second return value in matlab?

Tags: matlab

e.g. I have a function `[A, B, C] = foo(vargin)`. Now I ONLY want the second return value B. Is there any way to get only B without keeping A and C in place or modifying my function code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way is this: `[~, B] = foo(vargin)`. Works since Matlab 2009b I think

Comment: (Valid for matlab 2010+ I think)

Comment: You type quicker than me :-)

Comment: @am304 That's because you wasted precious time typing that extraneous second `~` ;) but +1 for you anyway

Comment: Oh, come on. It is NOT that messy. In fact, there are several ways to do this trivially even without the ~.

Comment: @woodchips I'll remove that sentence if it upsets you. Perhaps you can post the alternatives?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747296/how-to-elegantly-ignore-some-return-values-of-a-matlab-function

Answer (score 5):

```
[~,B,~] = foo(vargin)
```

I think it doesn't work in older versions of MATLAB, but can't remember for sure when `~` was introduced.