# Function from a multivariable function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, return-value

I have a function that returns three values `[A,B,C]=ABC(x)`.

Is it possible to define a function `A(x)` in an elegant way such that returns the first value of `ABC(x)`, `B(x)` for the second value, etc.?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Not completely clear whether you really mean that `ABC` returns a vector, or that it returns three values (each of which might be any object). If you really mean "vector" with three elements, `[A B C]`. then you could do:

```
function a = A(x)
temp = ABC(x);
a = temp(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

As you wrote your function (`[A,B,C]=ABC(x)`) it does not return a vector per say, it returns 3 values.

If you call your function like this

```
a = ABC(x)
```

`a` would be equal to `A`.

EDIT :

```
function b = B(x)
[~, b, ~] = ABC(x)
end
```

Comment: You're right but I also would like to obtain the second value. I edited the original post. Thanks.

Comment: You can also do [~, b, ~] = ABC(x) to get the second value. I don't really see why you want to have more functions.

Comment: I want to define a second function F=@(y,z) A(x)*y+B(z).

Comment: This is a nice clean solution. It does require a "somewhat recent" version of Matlab -the `~` notation was introduced with R2009. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/747439/1967396

Answer (score 0):

You could include a 2nd input argument if it is acceptable to you. You could use `varargin` to accept variable number of input arguments.

```
function outValue=ABC(varargin);

if nargin==0
   error('Need at least one argument');
elseif nargin==1
   %obtain result
   outValue=result;
elseif nargin==2
   %obtain result
   outValue=result(index);
else
   error('Function accepts maximum of 2 arguments');
end

end
```