# fminsearch to optimise n'th output in Matlab

Tags: matlab, fminsearch

Is there an elegant way to call `fminsearch` to optimise the n'th output of a function? or would one need to define a new function that returns the n'th output of the original function and apply `fminsearch` to this new function?

EDITED FOR CLARIFICATION:

i.e. given:

function [out1, out2] = myfunc(x)

% appropriate code

end

what is the simplest way to find the value of x that minimises out2?

Comment: This: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1344794/3139711 could be an option, but if this is more elegant than your intent to define a new function is open to dispute...

Comment: I'd seen that post before, but like you said, it's rather similar to defining a new function (just more generally applicable). I was hoping for more of a one line solution, but perhaps that's just not possible.

Answer (score 0):

If your function is called `foo`:

```
function foo(i,...,x)

end
```

You can either define a named function:

```
function foo_x(x)
   foo(...,x);
end
```

Or use anonymous functions:

```
@(x) foo(...,x)
```

and pass it to fminsearch.

---

There is another way, which is being (ab)used frequently, using local functions to assign the inputs. I don't recommend it, since it breaks a lot of good software engineering practices.

Comment: thanks for the reply! It seems you're looking at optimising a single-output function for a particular input, whereas I'm trying to optimise a multiple-output function, but for just one output. i.e. I have function [out1,out2] = myfunc(x) and I want to find the value of x that minimises out2. Thanks again!