# How to elegantly ignore return value of Matlab's subsasgn?

Tags: matlab

I have a class redefining the default subscript assignment (subsasgn).
Since it is a wrapper around memmapfile, I do not need the return value of subsasgn, so how do I ignore it?

Linked to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747296/how-to-elegantly-ignore-some-return-values-of-a-matlab-function) question, but trying to ignore all returned arguments :

```
dummy = subsasgn(self.mmap.Data.bit, newSub, value);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will be detected as "output requested" but not stored.

```
[~] = subsasgn(self.mmap.Data.bit, newSub, value);
```

However, this is for the case when something internal of `subsasgn` will not compute in the case that outputs are not requested (coded with some `nargout` check). For a general function where this does not happen you can just do:

```
subsasgn(self.mmap.Data.bit, newSub, value);
```

As I do not have the source code I can not guess which one you need.